# How to intercept default "rowclick" handler

Tags: jquery

Is there any possibilities to replace default "rowclick" jqGrid's method? By default, a row highlighting is appears after the mouse click. I need to remove this effect and handle row appearence manualy. Is this possible?

P.S: this code did not help me

```
$("#grid").unbind("click");
$("#grid").unbind("rowclick");
$("#grid").on("rowclick", function(event){return false;});
```

Row highlighting still appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("grid").on("rowclick", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);
});
```

Comment: solved by adding _selectionmode: 'none'_ to the grid attributes and  handling selected_position using API